# How to get the element of an array with a specific value

Tags: c#, xna

I need to get an element of an 2D-array which has one bool true.
It´s the only one with this boolean.

```
public void getCurrentTile()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 75; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 75; y++)
        {
            if (((Tile)grid[y, x]).lit)
            {
                current = (Tile)grid[y, x];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my current code. It seems to not work correctly. It only returns a current when one tile is lit. When another tile is lit it´s not returning a tile.

Code of Tile:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;


namespace SimMedieval
{
    public class Tile
    {
        public int size;
        public String path;
        public Texture2D texture;
        public bool lit = false;
        public bool lightable;
        MouseState mouseState;
        public System.Drawing.Color color;
        public int posX;
        public int posY;

        public Tile(int s, String texturepath, bool light)
        {
            size = s;
            path = texturepath;
            lightable = light;

        }

        public void load(Game game, Game1 game1, System.Drawing.Color colour)
        {
            color = colour;
            texture = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(path);
            game1.tiles.Add(this);
        }
        public void render(SpriteBatch sprites,int x, int y, Camera cam, Tile[,] grid)
        {
            mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
            float camPosX = (x * size) + cam.posX;
            float camPosY = (y * size) + cam.posY;
            if (-20 < camPosX && camPosX < 960 && -20 < camPosY && camPosY < 640)
            {
                if (new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1).Contains((mouseState.X / size) - ((int)Math.Round(cam.posX) / size), (mouseState.Y / size) - ((int)Math.Round(cam.posY) / size)))
                {
                    lit = true;
                    grid[y, x] = this;
                    sprites.Draw(texture, new Vector2((x * size) + cam.posX, (y * size) + cam.posY), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Coral);
                }
                else
                {
                    lit = false;
                    grid[y, x] = this;
                    sprites.Draw(texture, new Vector2((x * size) + cam.posX, (y * size) + cam.posY), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.White);
                }
            }
        }

        public void spawn(int x, int y, Tile[,] grid)
        {
            grid[y, x] = this;
            posX = x;
            posY = y;
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: I don't understand. On one hand you say `It's the only one with this boolean`, but then you say `When another tile is lit`. So can there be more than one tile or not?

Comment: Yup, you probably forget to unlit a tile when choosing a new current, or something like that. Or perhaps there really is no lit tile. Check out both answers for nicer approach on this (to sum it up - you should actually return the found tile, null if unfound, and handle the result from the caller, instead of assigning from within the function)

Comment: Let me explain it. There is always one tile lit. Never another one. But my code just returns a tile when tile, let´s say, #20 is lit. But when tile #13 is lit and #20 not nothing is returned.

Comment: can you show the code of `Tile`? is `lit` is Nullable?

Comment: @Hobbit9797 any issues with my answer?

Comment: yes, there are. Same error, so I guess it´s all about my code in Tile.cs @Damith

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, I think:

```
public Tile getCurrentTile()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 75; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 75; y++)
            if (((Tile)grid[y, x]).lit)
                return (Tile)grid[y, x];

    return null; // Return null if not found.
}
```

Instead of setting `current` inside the search function, it's clearer to make it return the found item, or `null` if it can't be found.

Then your calling code would look more like this:

```
var item = getCurrentTile();

if (item != null)
    current = item;
else
    // Code to handle no current tile being found.
```

Alternatively (and much simpler) you can just use Linq:

```
Tile item = grid.Cast<Tile>().FirstOrDefault(cell => cell.lit);

if (item != null)
    current = item;
else
    // Code to handle no current tile being found.
```

That's efficient because it will stop iterating as soon as it finds the first item.

If you want to throw an exception if none is found at all, do this:

```
Tile item = grid.Cast<Tile>().First(cell => cell.lit);
```

This will also stop iterating as soon as an item is found. This is the one I'd use because it's most efficient, and it also expresses the idea that one of them *must* match the predicate. It means that you know the returned `item` will never be null - however, it will of course throw an exception if *none* of the elements match the predicate.

However, if you wanted to throw an exception if none or more than one is found, you'd do this:

```
Tile item = grid.Cast<Tile>().Single(cell => cell.lit);
```

That will always iterate through *all* elements, because it's the only way it could check if more than one element matches the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to find the item you want. but first you need to convert 2D array in to `IEnumerable<T>` but how? if your `grid` contains objects of `Tile` then try below simple one line solution.

```
Tile current= (from Tile item in array
                   where item!=null && item.lit select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: How to cast from current to a Tile?